# Vertical alignment for multiple elements in header with scrlayer-scrpage

Tags: header-footer, koma-script, fancyhdr, scrlayer-scrpage

I have recently started using the `koma-script` classes, but I am having trouble transitioning from `fancyhdr` to `scrlayer-scrpage`. I want to place a logo on the right side and a mark on the left side. However, with `scrlayer-scrpage` the vertical alignment is not as expected. This is what I've tried so far

```
\documentclass[headsepline]{scrreprt}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage[hmargin=2.5cm, vmargin=2.5cm, headheight=40pt] {geometry}

%----------This does not work as expected------------
\usepackage[automark]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\clearpairofpagestyles
\ihead{\headmark}
\ohead{\includegraphics[height=12mm]{example-image-a}}
\cfoot*{\pagemark}

%---------This is what i want------------------------
%\usepackage{fancyhdr}
%\pagestyle{fancy}
%\lhead{\leftmark}
%\rhead{\includegraphics[height=12mm]{example-image-a}}
%\cfoot{\thepage}
%\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{1.2pt}

\begin{document}
\blinddocument
\end{document}
```

The output of the `scrlayer-scrpage`

[image: scrlayer-scrpage solution]

And the output using `fancyhdr`

[image: fancyhdr solution]

Without adding the image with `\ohead`, the mark behaves the same as in the `fancyhdr` solution. Somehow, adding the image changes the alignment.

How can i change my code to vertically align the mark at the bottom of the `headsepline`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can hide the height of the image:

```latex
\ohead{\smash{\includegraphics[height=12mm]{example-image-a}}}
```

Example:

```latex
\documentclass[headsepline]{scrreprt}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage[hmargin=2.5cm, vmargin=2.5cm, headheight=40pt] {geometry}

\usepackage[automark]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\clearpairofpagestyles
\ihead{\headmark}
\ohead{\smash{\includegraphics[height=12mm]{example-image-a}}}
\cfoot*{\pagemark}

\begin{document}
\blinddocument
\end{document}
```

[image]

Or with uppercase page header and changed width of headsepline:

```latex
\documentclass[headsepline]{scrreprt}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage[hmargin=2.5cm, vmargin=2.5cm, headheight=40pt] {geometry}

\usepackage[
  automark,
  markcase=upper,
  headsepline=1.2pt
]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\addtokomafont{pageheadfoot}{\upshape}
\renewcommand*{\chaptermarkformat}{\chaptername~\thechapter\autodot~~}

\clearpairofpagestyles
\ihead{\headmark}
\ohead{\smash{\includegraphics[height=12mm]{example-image-a}}}
\cfoot*{\pagemark}

\begin{document}
\blinddocument
\end{document}
```

[image]